# How to check all items in a loop have post thumbnail?

Tags: loop, post-thumbnails, php

Currently I have the following loop:

```
<?php
$shows_sales = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'show_sale',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
));
$done_image = false;
?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($shows_sales as $post) : setup_postdata($post) ?>
        <?php if (!$done_image && (has_post_thumbnail())) : ?>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage'); ?></a>
                <?php $done_image = true; ?>
            </li>   
        <?php else : ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>   
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

It will show one 'active' list item if post contains featured image, others just show the title in a normal list item.

What I need to add is a check that if none of the posts have a feature image, then insert a list item at the top of the unordered list.

I'm can't get my head around how to say '*if none have post thumbnail then show this else do the above*'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do your output, do something like this:

```
$no_thumbnails = true;
foreach( $shows_sales as $p ) {
    if( has_post_thumbnail( $p->ID ) )
        $no_thumbnails = false;
}
```

Then in your loop you can do something like this:

```
<?php if( $no_thumbnails === true ) : ?>
    <!-- Your output here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Perfect - I have gone with this method as it was easier for me to implement. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add the item to the beginning of the list, then you'll need to assemble the HTML *before* echoing it. Something like this:

```
<?php
$shows_sales = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'show_sale',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
));
$found_post_thumbnail = false;

// Assemble the HTML for the list items first
$list_items = ''
if ( $shows_sales->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $shows_sales->have_posts() ) {
        $shows_sales->the_post();

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $list_items .= '<li class="active"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage' ) . '</a></li>';
            $found_post_thumbnail = true;
        } else {
            $list_items .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
}

if ( !$found_post_thumbnail ) {
    $list_items = '<li>THIS IS MY EXTRA LIST ITEM</li>' . $list_items;
}

echo $list_items;
?>
```

I switched this to a `WP_Query` request instead of `get_posts()` plus `setup_postdata()` - `WP_Query` is a bit more of a standardized (and nesting-safe) way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have an awful lot of content within my list items though, stripped it back to ask the initial question, so I panicked and went for the other option. Thanks though :)

Comment: OK. The downside of the other option is that you end up looping through the items twice, which - depending on the number of items involved - could mean a hit on efficiency. But the most important thing is that you've got it working, optimized or not :)